# Meteor.userId() undefined in Iron Router Route After Logging In

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

When a user first loads the site without logging in, then logs in, the route `account` defined below will resolve to `/profile/null`. The user must refresh the site before the route's path becomes correct.

```
this.route('account', {
    template: 'profile',
    path: '/profile/' + Meteor.userId()
})
```

The reason for creating a route specially to take the parameter `Meteor.userId()` is because I'm using a [package](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) that requires me to define the `path` name, ie: `{{> ionTab title="Account" path="account"}}` which I dont think can take a parameter.

Whats the better way to refine this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route definition happens once when your app is started, at this time `Meteor.userId()` is still undefined, so that's why your code is not working, but the whole approach is wrong, you should instead define your route as follow :

```
Router.route("/profile/:_id",{
  name:"profile",
  template:"profile",
  waitOn:function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe("userProfile",this.params._id);
  },
  data:function(){
    var user=Meteor.users.findOne(this.params._id);
    return {
      user:user
    };
  }
});
```

What you may have missed in the `iron:router` docs is the possibility to define routes taking a parameter (`/path/:param` syntax) and use this parameter to configure the route subscriptions and data context.

EDIT

If you want to get the corresponding dynamic path for this route, you can use the `path` method :

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{> ionTab title="Account" path=accountPath}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  accountPath:function(){
    return Router.path("profile",Meteor.user());
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a [package](https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic) that requires me to define the `path` name, ie: `{{> ionTab title="Account" path="account"}}` which I dont think can take a parameter

Comment: Check my edit, you can get the dynamically computed route path customized by the parameter. The route parameter name should match the property in the object passed as second argument to `Router.path`.

Comment: Got the correct path in the browser JS console when I used `Router.path('profile', {'user_id': Meteor.userId()})`. Using `Router.path("profile",Meteor.user());` gave a `null` though...

Comment: Additionally, no href was created for `{{> ionTab}}` :( Note that I did not define `waitOn` and `data` in the route definition. Maybe passing the actual url into `path` parameter of `ionTab` template doesnt work...